# Why am I allowed to call this->deviceContext->map() from a const member function?

Tags: c++, constants, direct3d, const-correctness, direct3d11

I don't understand why this is allowed:

```
void Renderer::UpdateTextureFromArray(unsigned int* colors, unsigned int size, TextureData* textureData) const
{
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    this->deviceContext->Map(textureData->texture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);

    memcpy(ms.pData, colors, sizeof(unsigned int) * size * size);
    this->deviceContext->Unmap(textureData->texture, 0);
}
```

I made the UpdateTextureFromArray function const, yet I'm still allowed to call a non-const function on its members?

In this case, is it bad style for me to label the function as const?

EDIT:  To clarify, is it "lying" to society if I have a function like this const?  In a perfect world, this code wouldn't compile, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably `deviceContext` is a pointer data member, so a `const` method cannot modify the pointer. But is is allowed to modify the object the pointer points to:

```
struct Bar {
  void bar() {} // non const method
};

struct Foo {
  Foo() : p(0) {}
  void foo() const { p->bar();} // const method calling non-const method of Bar
  Bar* p;
};

int main()
{
  const Foo f;
  f.foo();  // OK, Foo::p is not modified
}
```

Comment: @MattSwarthout `const` means you cannot modify data members of call non-const member functions. your data member is a pointer, which you are not modifying... you just have to be careful with pointers.

Comment: I understand that now, but I don't see how "const" affords any sort of protection or guarantees if it doesn't check for this.  When you dereference "this", it returns a const "this", and still doesn't let you call const functions.  Why doesn't dereferencing your own members do the same?

Comment: @MattSwarthout `this` is a special case, passed as implicit first parameters to member functions. When the function is `const`, `this` points to a `const` object.

Comment: i.e. in a const member function `this` has type `const Foo* const`, in a non-const member function it has type `Foo* const`

Comment: Okay.  But, why?  I'm asking why is it like that if it essentially does nothing in most cases.  What's the point?  Did they actively choose that it is okay to modify data a member points to from a const function, or is there a technical reason they couldn't have the compiler give an error?  It makes no sense.

Comment: @MattSwarthout note that you can always write a light wrapper that holds the pointer, and exports a const-correct interface. You then hold an instance in your class.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, it's just different to your expectations. The type a pointer points to is set by the type system. A pointer to `Foo` does not become a pointer to `const Foo` just because you access it in a `const` member, or bind a const reference to it and use that.

Comment: Well, it does NOT make sense, but it does follow consistent rules.  My question was "Why are the rules what they are?"  According to the wikipedia article, it's just because changing it now would break existing code.

Comment: Just repeating it doesn't make sense doesn't make it true, it just means you don't understand it yet. The alternative wouldn't work, so doing it wouldn't make sense. Read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html and consider that the implicit "deep-constness" that you expect would be equivalent to doing those sort of problematic conversions invisibly

Comment: No, it does not make sense.  If you can change the state of an object in a const member function, then "const" means nothing.

Comment: @MattSwarthout you are not changing the state of anything the class owns. The class holds a pointer. The pointer does not get changed. Simple. 2-1 it makes sense :-)

Comment: But if the pointer points to a data member of the class, then that is again violated.  It still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling a non-const function on its member, you're dereferencing its member (which doesn't modify it, so is allowed to be done with a `const` pointer) and then calling a non-const member on the result of that dereference.

Comment: I see.  I just assumed the constness would propagate through the dereference.

Comment: No, the result of dereferencing a `Foo* const` is the same as the result of dereferencing `Foo*`, it's `Foo&` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling non-const function on its members, you are accessing a pointer (which is const) which is pointing to a non-const object. You are thereby able to call non-const functions on it.

Regarding style, a const method is a method that doesn't change the state of the object from the users viewpoint. So you have to consider yourself if this pointer access does this or not. Some classes are candidates for parallelization in which case const methods are regarded as safe methods to parallelize as they are supposed to be without side effects.

So to qualify a method for const, I would suggest that it:

- Isn't a candidate for parallelization and have no user visible side effects
- Is a candidate for parallelization but have proper synchronization or no side effects at all.